# Android - Landscape does not go back into the portrait

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to make differant layouts for portrait and landscape. Everything is OK on android 5.1+, but on android 5.0 when I'm starting on portrait then switch to landscape and again switch to portrait - the vertical orientation is great but here are still landscape layout.

I'm using just simple thing:

```
layout
    content_main.xml
layout-land
    content_main.xml
```

Manifest.xml on mainactivity

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation"
```

layout-land/content_main.xml

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

layout/content_main.xml

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

What more must I do? Thanks!

portrait (first launch) - OK

Comment: have you set orientation in activity tag in menifest?

Comment: try this android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screensize"

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal Yes, I wrote it ...

Comment: @Raman that works! great, thanks... can you write an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this
android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screensize"

this should come together android:configChanges= "orientation|screensize" always